# In WinRT how do I prevent a click in the Slider tickbar?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

IN XAML we have a simple slider control. We want to disable clicking in the tick bar, but still allow the user to use the slider thumb grabber thingy. Any ideas?

Comment: [Disable clicking on a Slider track](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75a44a31-940e-40c1-88d5-4a7c77b2fe48/disable-clicking-on-a-slider-track)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the slider template in Blend and set `IsHitTestVisible` on `TopTickBar`/`BottomTickBar`/`Both`(as applicable) to `false`.

Should work.